# Why will always use anonymous function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I see almost tutorial use anonymous function in AngularJS, instead of normal function, like function name(para1) {}. Please see this link: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_controller_property

I change to normal function, but it cannot work, Please advise. Thanks.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl as main">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{main.fullName()}}

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    function fullName() {
        return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
    };
});
</script>
```

Comment: if you want to use named function you can do something like declare funcion as you do .. and then assign it like: $scope. fullName = fullName;

Comment: Yes. I tried, it can work if we add function name(){}. But I have to assign it to  $scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of $scope is to have an object where all fields and functions are defined on, so that you are able to reference the fields and functions from your template.

When you don't attach the function to `$scope` it will not be visible for angular to be called. So the contract is that in your controller function, you add everything you need to the `$scope` object passed by the framework and by doing so, you can later access the fields or call the functions from your template. Everything you reference in directives like `ng-model` or put into `{{ }}` will be evaluated by angular, but angular doesn't know what you mean with the expression `fullName()` as written in your snippet link or fails finding it in the controller when written as `main.fullName()`.

For details on the concept of `$scope` have a look at [the angular docs on scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

Comment: I got. Can you give me some reference document so that I can read more?

Comment: Have a look at the angular docs on scopes. I added the link to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do (and it is also a good practice) is to declare your function and then (maybe in tha init of the controlelr) assign them to the $scope ..so is more clear when you'll re read it something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{fullName()}}

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    $scope.fullName = fullName; //<-- here you assign it


    function fullName() {
        return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is want I want. I also see something similar as you did.

Comment: happy if hepled you .. if it is .. plz rate it .. :-) thnx!

Comment: I will rate it after my reputation become 15. Thanks a lot. Have a wonderful weekend.